# Grabbing text from multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I grab the text from multiple input fields using jquery. Currently my function looks like this

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#inputDiv").text($("input").val());
})
```

This only grabs from the first input field however how do I make it take the value of every field

Here is a fiddle of my work so far: http://jsfiddle.net/YqWv2/3/

Comment: Use [`$("input").each(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Would you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/v76gk/

Comment: @SpYk3HH Yes but they would be separate elements eventually I want to make a form with the elements that you can later add values to

Comment: yeah, no prob stick with the `.each` suggestions and learn to make more use of class-names as opposed to id's, just a suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#inputDiv").empty();
    $('input').each(function () {
        $("#inputDiv").append($(this).val()).append('<br/>');
    });
})
```

You need to loop through all the fields

Comment: This doesn't escape HTML. It's better to `$("#inputDiv").text($("#inputDiv").text() + $(this).val());`

Comment: @blgt also I wanted to add a br after each entry and .text() will overwrite everything.

Comment: @Silkster It doesn't matter, you always have to escape user input or risk being [XSS-ed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: @blgt noted, but that's a different issue altogether.

Comment: Besides, I don't want to do all the work for the OP ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `.map` method to get all the values and append them to the appropriate element.

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#inputDiv").text( 
       $("input").map(function() { return this.value; }).get().join(',') 
    );
});
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/YqWv2/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version

```
$("#submit").click(function() {    
    var str = "";
    $("input").each(function(e){
        var currentItem = $(this).val();
        str = str + currentItem;
    });
    $("#inputDiv").html(str);
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aknatn/Vh2NA/1/)